# How to return all the rows in the yellow census blocks?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hey the schema is like this: for the whole dataset, we should order by machine_id first, then order by ss2k. after that, for each machine, we should find all the rows with at least consecutively 5 flag = 'census'. In this dataset, the result should be all the yellow rows..

I cannot return the last 4 rows of the yellow blocks by using this:

```
drop table if exists qz_panel_census_228_rank;
create table qz_panel_census_228_rank as
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where flag = 'census') over (partition by machine_id, date order by ss2k rows between current row and 4 following) as census_cnt5,
             count(*) filter (where flag = 'census') over (partition by machine_id, date) as count_census,
             row_number() over (partition by machine_id, date order by ss2k) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by machine_id, date) as cnt
      from qz_panel_census_228 t
     ) t
where census_cnt5 = 5 
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
DISTRIBUTED BY (machine_id);
```

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We usually like to help people, not just do everything for them - unless it's fairly simple.

Comment: @ADyson I just edit my post.

Answer (score 2):

You were close, but you need to search in both directions:

```
   select t.*
    from (select t.*,
            case when count(*) filter (where flag = 'census')
                      over (partition by machine_id, date
                            order by ss2k
                            rows between 4 preceding and current row) = 5 
                   or count(*) filter (where flag = 'census') 
                      over (partition by machine_id, date
                            order by ss2k
                            rows between current row and 4 following) = 5
                 then 1
                 else 0
             end  as flag
          from qz_panel_census_228 t
         ) t
    where flag = 1
```

Edit:

This approach will not work unless you add an extra count for each possible 5 row window, e.g. 3 preceding and 1 following, 2 preceding and 2 following, etc. This results in ugly code and is not very flexible.

The common way to solve this *gaps & islands* problem is to assign consecutive rows to a common group first:

```
    select *
    from 
     ( 
        select t2.*,
           count(*) over (partition by machine_id, date, grp) as cnt
        from
          (
           select t1.*
            from (select t.*,
                    -- keep the same number for 'census' rows
                    sum(case when flag = 'census' then 0 else 1 end)
                    over (partition by machine_id, date
                          order by ss2k
                          rows unbounded preceding) as grp
                  from qz_panel_census_228 t
          ) t1
         where flag = 'census' -- only census rows
      ) as t2
) t3
     where cnt >= 5  -- only groups of at least 5 census rows
```

Comment: Wow,,, @dnoeth you are so smart. I have to say that. Let me try the code on my data,.

Comment: I'm just doing this kind of logic using Window Functions for almost 20 years now :-)

Comment: Hey @dnoeth, I tried this code on my data. It seems when the length of the yellow census block is 5, the code will only return the 1st row and the 5th row. For example, in the first yellow census block, only the 1st and 5th rows will be returned. Is there a way to return all the rows in the blocks? Thanks

Comment: Oops, correct. I don't think you can get the expected result using this approach. Wait a minute...

Comment: Hi @dnoeth, Thanks for everything. But it seems this code returns almost all the census rows in the data, instead of of only the census rows in the yellow blocks. I tried the code in my data..

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add `grp` to the partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, there has to be a better way of doing this, but the only way I could figure out was to create blocks of consecutive 'census' values.  This looks awful but might be a catalyst to a better idea.

```
with q1 as (
  select
    machine_id, recorded, ss2k, flag, date,
    case
      when flag = 'census' and
        lag (flag) over (order by machine_id, ss2k) != 'census'
          then 1
      else 0
    end as block
  from foo
),
q2 as (
  select
    machine_id, recorded, ss2k, flag, date,
    sum (block) over (order by machine_id, ss2k) as group_id,
    case when flag = 'census' then 1 else 0 end as census
  from q1
),
q3 as (
  select 
    machine_id, recorded, ss2k, flag, date, group_id,
    sum (census) over (partition by group_id order by ss2k) as max_count
  from q2
),
groups as (
  select group_id
  from q3
  group by group_id
  having max (max_count) >= 5
)
select
  q2.machine_id, q2.recorded, q2.ss2k, q2.flag, q2.date
from
  q2
  join groups g on q2.group_id = g.group_id
where
  q2.flag = 'census'
```

If you run each query within the `with` clauses in isolation, I think you will see how this evolves.